# summation of outputs from a data file

Tags: python, for-loop, text, sum, data-files

I would like to sum numbers in a text file(1.txt) containing the following numbers

```
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

If we run the following code we can reach the outputs written under this code:

```
q=0
def func(x,y):
   h=y+i
   return x+h
for i in range(1,5):
   with open('1.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line=line.strip()
            c= list(map(float, line.split()))
            q=(func(c[0],c[1]))
            print(q,i)

outputs:============
q= 12.0 i= 1
q= 23.0 i= 1
q= 34.0 i= 1
q= 13.0 i= 2
q= 24.0 i= 2
q= 35.0 i= 2
q= 14.0 i= 3
q= 25.0 i= 3
q= 36.0 i= 3
q= 15.0 i= 4
q= 26.0 i= 4
q= 37.0 i= 4
```

this code is working properly but the problem is:
i would like to have the summation of "q"s related to each "i" in out put.For example

```
q=12+23+34, i=1
q=13+24+35, i=2
q=14+25+36, i=3
q=15+26+37, i=4
```

***Please note that the functions in this example are simplified and they can be each complicated function.***
I appreciate your attention and your help.

Comment: Why are you reading the same text file 4 times?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to what data you put in and what you want out as a result. Please elaborate and clarify the section on "q"s and "i"s, as well as what you mean by the last statement about complicated functions and if we need to take this into account in our answers.

Comment: Do you literally want the output to look like `q=12+23+34, i=1`, or do you want those `q` numbers to be added together?

Comment: I just wrote q=12+23+34, i=1 to be clear what i want in out puts. and this is a clear question my friend,  i did not use it for 4 times, the i variable is a effective factor in a complicated calculations, i just simplified this code to be clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0

with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        c = list(map(float, line.split()))
        total += func(c[0],c[1])


for i in range(1,5):
    print("q={}, i={}".format(total+i, i))
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).